# constructor parameters are set automatically to tuple as a datatype

Tags: python, tuples

i have the below posted constructor.the values i set for the parameters of the constructor are as follows:

```
(
    config['DEFAULT']['selected_site_id'],config['DEFAULT']['threshold'],False,
    -99,-99,-99,-99,-99,-99,
    -99,-99,-99,-99,-99,-99,
    None,None
)
```

when i ran the code, i received an error about the datatype of the value set to the member variable/attribute `heightsMean`. to fix that issue, i used the print-statements mentioned below to see what the datatype of the member variable/attribute `heightsMean` really is.
surprisingly, it was as follows:

```
print(type(self.heightsMean))#tuple
print(type(heightsMean))#string
exit()
```

can you please tell me why the datatype of `self.heightsMean` is tuple?

**code**:

```
def __init__(self,
             selectedSiteID,
             threshold,
             areCellsMeetsThreshold,
             areaOfCoverageMean,
             areaOfCoverageMedian,
             areaOfCoverageMax,
             areaOfCoverageMin,
             areaOfCoverageP90,
             areaOfCoverageP10,
             heightsMean,
             heightsMedian,
             heightsMax,
             heightsMin,
             heightsP90,
             heightsP10,
             fourCornersOfWindowsWithP25OrLowerOfInterceptionInTreatmentAsGeoJSON,
             fourCornersOfWindowsWithP25OrLowerOfInterceptionInBufferAsGeoJSON
             ):
    self.objInitTime = time.time()
    self.selectedSiteID = selectedSiteID
    self.threshold = threshold
    self.areCellsMeetsThreshold=areCellsMeetsThreshold
    self.areaOfCoverageMean=areaOfCoverageMean
    self.areaOfCoverageMedian=areaOfCoverageMedian
    self.areaOfCoverageMax=areaOfCoverageMax
    self.areaOfCoverageMin=areaOfCoverageMin
    self.areaOfCoverageP90=areaOfCoverageP90
    self.areaOfCoverageP10=areaOfCoverageP10
    self.heightsMean=heightsMean,
    print(type(self.heightsMean))#tuple
    print(type(heightsMean))#string
    exit()
```

Comment: `self.heightsMean=heightsMean,` the comma at the end makes it a `tuple`. Was it a typo?

Comment: @Axe319 thanks, it is solved the issue..i did not that preceeding a var with comma turns it inot a tuple

Comment: No problem. It's a common misconception that the parentheses `()` make a `tuple` but it is in fact the [comma](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) that does so. Adding a comma after a variable or literal makes it a one element `tuple`. Parentheses are required when passing as an argument to show your intent to pass it as a single argument rather than many.